# Making an array of spiral numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

### Context

I was solving a task on CodeSignal [here](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-12/uRWu6K8E7uLi3Qtvx)

You can view the task on the link I provided above.

I have also put the task at the bottom of the post.

### Code

```
def check(matrix, num):
    for arr in matrix:
        for number in arr:
            if number != num:
                return True
    return False


def spiralNumbers(n):
    array = []
    array_dup = []
    for i in range(n):
        arr1 = []
        for j in range(n):
            arr1.append(j)
        array.append(arr1)

    for i in range(n):
        arr1 = []
        for j in range(n):
            arr1.append(j)
        array_dup.append(arr1)


    selected_row, selected_num_pos = 0, -1
    count = 1
    run = True
    while run:
        its_neg = False
        for i in range(selected_num_pos+1, n):
            if array_dup[selected_row][i] == -1:
                its_neg = True
                break
            array[selected_row][i] = count
            array_dup[selected_row][i] = -1
            count += 1
        if its_neg:
            selected_num_pos = i-1
        else:
            selected_num_pos = i

        its_neg = False
        for i in range(selected_row+1, n):
            if array_dup[i][selected_num_pos] == -1:
                its_neg = True
                break
            array[i][selected_num_pos] = count
            array_dup[i][selected_num_pos] = -1
            count += 1
        if its_neg:
            selected_row = i-1
        else:
            selected_row = i

        its_neg = False
        for i in range(selected_num_pos-1, -1, -1):
            if array_dup[selected_row][i] == -1:
                its_neg = True
                break
            array[selected_row][i] = count
            array_dup[selected_row][i] = -1
            count += 1
        if its_neg:
            selected_num_pos = i+1
        else:
            selected_num_pos = i

        its_neg = False
        for i in range(selected_row-1, -1, -1):
            if array_dup[i][selected_num_pos] == -1:
               its_neg = True
               break
            array[i][selected_num_pos] = count
            array_dup[i][selected_num_pos] = -1
            count += 1
        if its_neg:
            selected_row = i+1
        else:
            selected_row = i

        run = check(array_dup, -1)

    return array
```

### Question

The Code I wrote works without any error and returns the expected output, but the code seems a bit long for this problem. I wanted to know how can I make this code shorter and more efficient?

### The Task

[image]

Comment: Are there no lower/upper limits for N?

Comment: An outline describing your method would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You're using non-standard names. Usual names are A for the matrix, i for the row index, and j for the column index.
- List repetition and comprehension make the initialization shorter and faster.
- Using deltas for the four directions can avoid quadrupling code.
- You can know when to change direction by checking whether the next element in the current direction is already set.
- Your `check` is inefficient. Instead of searching the matrix for an unset spot, just do `while count <= n**2:`. Or, try to loop through the `range` of numbers.
- Your current code crashes for `n = 0` because it always enters the loop, as you compute `run` only at the end. With `while count <= n**2:` you'd succeed.

```
def spiralNumbers(n):
    A = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
    i = j = di = 0
    dj = 1
    for A[i][j] in range(1, n**2 + 1):
        if A[(i+di) % n][(j+dj) % n]:
            di, dj = dj, -di
        i += di
        j += dj
    return A
```

The `% n` is just a little trick to avoid checking for index-out-of-bounds.